# Excel SUMIF - If condition is met then SUM two cells in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table like this:

```
TABLE A

NAME     VALUE 1   VALUE 2   RESULT
Daniel   1         4
John     3         5
Daniel   5         8
```

I’d like to run a `SUMIF` within the RESULT column, and if a condition is met, instead of adding up only one column I’d like both VALUES to be added. I know I can achieve this by doing two `SUMIF`s, but I’d like to know if is it possible to do it using only one and then make my code more readable. 
The function should look like this:

```
SUMIF(TableA[Name], "Daniel", SUM(TableA[Value1],TableA[Value2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you realized, this isn’t really a job for `SUMIF`. 
You don’t even need `SUM`; this works (in Column `D`):

```
=IF(A2="Daniel", B2+C2, 0)
```

or

```
=IF(TableA[Name]="Daniel", TableA[Value1]+TableA[Value2], 0)
```

in table syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a workaround:

```
SUM((TableA[Name]="Daniel")*(TableA[Value1]),(TableA[Name]="Daniel")*(TableA[Value2]))
```